# Fast, secure, and reliable web server for static content

Tags: linux, web-server

I need a fast, secure, stable, light, and reliable server for static web content. I'll run this server inside Alpine Linux (or whatever distro) containers. Security and stability are important for me, I don't need any bloated features. Any propositions?

Answer (score 1):

`nginx` is the way to go. You said you do not want to be bloated, that's why I did not answer apache server.
Most companies are switching to nginx for this reason.
Either way shoul should be fine. Both are secure and high available.

Also, I see they are available for linux, but Windows Server is better as far as I know for this things, because of performance.